# Can the invention from this patent be used in a research project in pharmacy?

Tags: ep1870511a1

In reference to the patent: [EP1341498A4](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1341498A4)

Answer (score 1):

Patent rights do not, in principle, extend to research activities. This means that universities and other research institutes are free to use patented technology within the course of their activities, provided that they are strictly for academic pursposes and not for business activities. A good overview of this and the legislation behind it can be found in the below article:

"Safe harbors in Europe: an update on the research and
Bolar exemptions to patent infringement", *Nature Biotechnology*, 2015, volume 33, p.710

Similar provisions exist worldwide, having their origins in Article 30 of the TRIPS agreement.

There seems to be a blur borderline between the terms "on the patented invention" vs "with the patented invention", but this depends on the details of each case.

In your reference, EP1341498**A4** is the *search report* of patent *application* EP1341498**A2**, which never got granted, so it doesn't matter anyway.